# Kendo Grid vertical scrollbar doesn't appear only horizontal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I use Kendo Grid scrolling, as every other grids in my project. I have this grid, where horizontal scrolling works, but vertical doesn't appear.

I've tried to set height of grid in HtmlAttributes setted height in .Scrollable() and added Enable in it.

```cs
@(Html.MaskableGrid<Elozmeny>("gridElozmenyek")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Command(commands =>
                        {
                            commands.Edit().Text("<span></span>").UpdateText("<span></span>").CancelText("<span></span>").HtmlAttributes(KendoHelper.EditHtmlAttributesFor(Model)).Visible("isEditable");
                            commands.Destroy().Text("<span></span>").Visible("buttonVisible");
                        }).Width(Constants.DEFAULT_GRID_COLUMN_WIDTH_NARROWER).Title("")
                        .HtmlAttributes(KendoHelper.DestroyHtmlAttributesFor(Model));
                        columns.Bound(m => m.ElozmenyId).Width(Constants.DEFAULT_GRID_COLUMN_WIDTH).Title("Előzmény azonosító").ClientTemplate("#= ElozmenyId == 0 ? ' ' : ElozmenyId #");
                        columns.Bound(m => m.EsemenyTipusKod).ClientTemplate("#= EsemenyTipus != null ? EsemenyTipus.Nev : EsemenyTipusKod #").EditorTemplateName("EsemenyTipusDropDownEditor").EditorViewData(new { EsemenyTipus = "#=EsemenyTipusKod#" }).Width(Constants.DEFAULT_GRID_COLUMN_WIDTH).Title("Esemény típus");
                        columns.Bound(m => m.Leiras).EditorTemplateName("LeirasInputEditor").Encoded(false).Width(Constants.DEFAULT_GRID_COLUMN_WIDTH_WIDER).Title("Leírás");
                        columns.Bound(m => m.Megjegyzes).EditorTemplateName("MegjegyzesInputEditor").Encoded(false).Width(Constants.DEFAULT_GRID_COLUMN_WIDTH_WIDER).Title("Megjegyzés");
                        columns.Bound(m => m.EsemenyIdeje).Format("{0:yyyy.MM.dd}").EditorTemplateName("Date").Width(Constants.DEFAULT_GRID_COLUMN_WIDTH).Title("Esemény ideje");
                        columns.Bound(m => m.BejegyzoMunkatarsNev).ClientTemplate("#= BejegyzoMunkatars != null ? BejegyzoMunkatars.Nev : currUser() #").Width(Constants.DEFAULT_GRID_COLUMN_WIDTH).Title("Bejegyző munkatárs").Editable("isEditable");
                        columns.Bound(m => m.VersionNumber).Hidden(true);
                    }).Events(x => x.Save("saveLeirasEsMegjegyzes").Edit("OnEditGridElozmeny"))
                    .ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Create().Text("<span></span>").HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "addButton"}))
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
                        .Model(model =>
                        {
                            model.Id(m => m.ElozmenyId);
                            model.Field(m => m.EsemenyTipus).DefaultValue(new EsemenyTipus() { Kod = "EGYEB", Nev = "Egyéb" });
                            model.Field(m => m.Leiras).Editable(true);
                            model.Field(m => m.Megjegyzes).Editable(true);
                            model.Field(m => m.EsemenyTipusKod);
                            model.Field(m => m.EsemenyIdeje).Editable(true);
                            model.Field(m => m.BejegyzoMunkatars).DefaultValue(new Munkatars() { MunkatarsId = User.Identity.GetMunkatarsId().Value, Nev = User.Identity.Name }).Editable(false);
                            model.Field(m => m.BejegyzoMunkatarsId).DefaultValue(User.Identity.GetMunkatarsId().Value);
                            model.Field(m => m.Eid).DefaultValue(Model.Entity.Eid).Editable(false);
                        })
                        .Read(read => read.Action("SelectElozmeny", "Epulet", new { epuletId = Model.Entity.Eid }))
                        .Destroy("DeleteElozmeny", "Elozmeny")
                        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateElozmeny", "Elozmeny"))
                        .Create("InsertElozmeny", "Elozmeny")
                        .Events(x => x.RequestEnd("elozmenyGridRequestEnding"))
                        .PageSize(10)
                        .Sort(sort => sort.Add(m => m.EsemenyIdeje).Descending())
                    )
                    .Filterable(KendoHelper.DefaultGridFilterConfig)
                    .Pageable(KendoHelper.DefaultPagerConfig)
                    .Sortable(sorter => { sorter.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn); sorter.AllowUnsort(false); })
                    .AutoBind(false)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 600px" })
                    .Scrollable(s => { s.Enabled(true); s.Height(250); })
                )
```

I expect both scrollbars to appear and become usable.

Comment: I've got the solution since. I've used `@(Html.Kendo.Grid().Name("gridElozmenyek")` instead of `@(Html.MaskableGrid<Elozmeny>("gridElozmenyek")`

Answer (score 0):

referring to Telerik forum [telerik forum](https://www.telerik.com/forums/horizontal-scroling-)

try to set up height to auto `.Scrollable(s => s.Height("auto"))`

also scrolling might depend on wrappers you have around this grid and their styling